# nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException:

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm new to Quartz and I'm just starting with a project already working with quartz scheduler. The Project is compiling but at runtime it throws the following exception:

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'galleryBulkTrigger' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-scheduler.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'galleryBulkJob' while setting bean property 'jobDetail'; nested exception is


org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'galleryBulkJob' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-scheduler.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required 
type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'jobClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.sgss.nove.quartz.gallery.GalleryBulkJob]:
```

The applicationcontext defines the beans as follows:

```
<bean id="galleryBulkTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="galleryBulkJob"/>
    <property name="cronExpression" value="#{noveExternalProperties['cronExpression.galleryBulk']}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="galleryBulkJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="com.sgss.nove.quartz.gallery.GalleryBulkJob"/>
    <property name="jobDataAsMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="galleryBulkTask" value-ref="galleryBulkTask"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and the class `GalleryBulkJob` is as follows:

```
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean;

public class GalleryBulkJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    private GalleryBulkTask galleryBulkTask;

    public void setGalleryBulkTask(GalleryBulkTask galleryBulkTask) {
        this.galleryBulkTask = galleryBulkTask;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {
        galleryBulkTask.executeTask();
    }
}
```

As long as I know it should work, the only doubt is the line: `<property name="jobClass" value="com.sgss.nove.quartz.gallery.GalleryBulkJob"/>` in which the value is seen as a string, but a Class is expected.

How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's OK to pass a string to a class argument in a Spring context. 
Take a look at the error message: Cannot find class [com.sgss.nove.quartz.gallery.GalleryBulkJob]. 
The class does not seem to exist on the class path by some reason.

Comment: I just had to rebuild the project, the class was there and wasn't recognized but in the next build it was recognized and the error went away so i guess it's fixed now.

Comment: Funny how we sometimes forget to think of the most basic steps... Thanks for the comment, I will myself try to never forget about the first step for any weird problem: rebuild the project.